# Why wont my PHP echo output as expected?

Tags: php, html, echo

I am trying to use a PHP echo to build a table on this page http://www.trackmymarks.com/teacher_analysis.php?year=7&class=7L/Sc1. Unfortunately, the echo command is not working as expected and I have no idea why. It seems to be failing to concatenate the strings correctly.

On line 120, the code fails to produce the necessary tags to format the table as I want it. Here is the PHP for the page:

```
<?php 
require "requires.php";
require "header.php";

echo "<title>TrackMyMarks - Teacher Analysis</title>";

$year = htmlspecialchars($_GET["year"]);
$class = htmlspecialchars($_GET["class"]);

echo "<h1>Teacher Analysis ".$class."</h1>";

if ((int)date("M") < 9) { $academicyear = date("Y") - 1; } else { $academicyear = date("Y"); }


$query = "SELECT * FROM Student INNER JOIN `Year ".$year."` ON Student.UPN = `Year ".$year."`.UPN AND Student.CurrentClass='".$class."' AND `Year ".$year."`.`Year Taken` = '" . $academicyear . "'";

echo $query;

$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["con"], $query);
if (!$result) 
{ 
    logwrite("MYSQL ERROR: " . mysqli_error($GLOBALS["con"]));
}

$retention = array(array(), array(), array(), array(), array(), array());
$PPIretention = array(array(), array(), array(), array(), array(), array());
$nPPIretention = array(array(), array(), array(), array(), array(), array());
$girlsretention = array(array(), array(), array(), array(), array(), array());
$boysretention = array(array(), array(), array(), array(), array(), array());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
//  print_r($row);

    if ($year == 7)
    {
        $TGLookup = "Year7_TG";
    } else {
        $TGLookup = "Year8_TG";
    }

    print_r($row);

    $targetCredits = lookup($row['Target Level'], $TGLookup);

    $studentRetention = array($row['Term 1 Mastery Test'] - $targetCredits, $row['Term 2 Mastery Test'] - $targetCredits, $row['Term 3 Mastery Test'] - $targetCredits, $row['Term 4 Mastery Test'] - $targetCredits, $row['Term 5 Mastery Test'] - $targetCredits, $row['Term 6 Mastery Test'] - $targetCredits);

    array_push($retention[0], $studentRetention[0]);
    array_push($retention[1], $studentRetention[1]);
    array_push($retention[2], $studentRetention[2]);
    array_push($retention[3], $studentRetention[3]);
    array_push($retention[4], $studentRetention[4]);
    array_push($retention[5], $studentRetention[5]);

    if ($row['PPI'] == 1) {
        array_push($PPIretention[0], $studentRetention[0]);
        array_push($PPIretention[1], $studentRetention[1]);
        array_push($PPIretention[2], $studentRetention[2]);
        array_push($PPIretention[3], $studentRetention[3]);
        array_push($PPIretention[4], $studentRetention[4]);
        array_push($PPIretention[5], $studentRetention[5]);
    } else {
        array_push($nPPIretention[0], $studentRetention[0]);
        array_push($nPPIretention[1], $studentRetention[1]);
        array_push($nPPIretention[2], $studentRetention[2]);
        array_push($nPPIretention[3], $studentRetention[3]);
        array_push($nPPIretention[4], $studentRetention[4]);
        array_push($nPPIretention[5], $studentRetention[5]);
    }

    if ($row['Gender'] == 'F') {
        array_push($girlsretention[0], $studentRetention[0]);
        array_push($girlsretention[1], $studentRetention[1]);
        array_push($girlsretention[2], $studentRetention[2]);
        array_push($girlsretention[3], $studentRetention[3]);
        array_push($girlsretention[4], $studentRetention[4]);
        array_push($girlsretention[5], $studentRetention[5]);
    } else {
        array_push($boysretention[0], $studentRetention[0]);
        array_push($boysretention[1], $studentRetention[1]);
        array_push($boysretention[2], $studentRetention[2]);
        array_push($boysretention[3], $studentRetention[3]);
        array_push($boysretention[4], $studentRetention[4]);
        array_push($boysretention[5], $studentRetention[5]);
    }


}

echo '

<div class="row">
<table class="table table-boardered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Term</th>
            <th>Average Retention</th>
            <th>HW Completion percentage</th>
            <th>PPI Gap</th>
            <th>Gender Gap</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Overall</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>';

for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++){
    if (count($retention[$i]) == 0) {$retentionAverage = 0;} else {$retentionAverage = array_sum($retention[$i])/count($retention[$i]);}
    if (count($PPIretention[$i]) == 0) {$PPIretentionAverage = 0;} else {$PPIretentionAverage = array_sum($PPIretention[$i])/count($PPIretention[$i]);}
    if (count($nPPIretention[$i]) == 0) {$nPPIretentionAverage = 0;} else {$nPPIretentionAverage = array_sum($nPPIretention[$i])/count($nPPIretention[$i]);}
    if (count($boysretention[$i]) == 0) {$boysretentionAverage = 0;} else {$boysretentionAverage = array_sum($boysretention[$i])/count($boysretention[$i]);}
    if (count($girlsretention[$i]) == 0) {$girlsretentionAverage = 0;} else {$girlsretentionAverage = array_sum($girlsretention[$i])/count($girlsretention[$i]);}

    echo $retentionAverage;

    echo '<tr><td>'. ($i + 1) .'</td><td>'. $retentionAverage .'</td><td>'. $PPIretentionAverage-$nPPIretentionAverage .'</td><td>'.' '.'</td><td>'. $girlsretentionAverage-$boysretentionAverage .'</td></tr>';
}
echo '
    </tbody>
</table>

';

include "footer.php";
?>
```

Comment: And which line is 120?

Comment: Try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Like 120 is     echo '<tr><td>'. ($i + 1) .'</td><td>'. $retentionAverage .'</td><td>'. $PPIretentionAverage-$nPPIretentionAverage .'</td><td>'.' '.'</td><td>'. $girlsretentionAverage-$boysretentionAverage .'</td></tr>';

Comment: You do realize that you're currently echoing `$retentionAberage` _between_ your `</tr><tr>` tags before that line as well?

Comment: try to put brackets around your substractions: `($PPIretentionAverage-$nPPIretentionAverage)`, if it doesn't work, be more precise on how your code are failing, what you expect instead, etc.

Comment: Try to declare variables out of if else block for example: first declare `$retentionAverage = 0;` then write `if (count($retention[$i]) != 0) { $retentionAverage = array_sum($retention[$i])/count($retention[$i]); }`  This will gives allow echo to use that variable. Also remove `echo $retentionAverage;`  Why your link prints "Overall" in the table. Is it the value got from any variable?

Comment: @SandeepKokate How would that change anything?

Comment: As @Kaddath said: you need to enclose your arithmetic in brackets, since otherwise your string parts will be "eaten up". That is why your current output is something like: `</tr>-74.97222222222275</td></tr>-74.02777777777872.384615384615</td></tr>-74.94444444444475</td></tr>-72.86111111111174.769230769231</td></tr>-74.91666666666775</td></tr>-71.2569.230769230769</td></tr>` ...

Comment: What I've done now is separated this out into a whole series of echo statements which works, before it was repeatedly echoing the `</td></tr>`

Comment: @cars10 Yes, you're exactly right, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the line:

```
echo '<tr><td>'. ($i + 1) .'</td><td>'. $retentionAverage .'</td><td>'. $PPIretentionAverage-$nPPIretentionAverage .'</td><td>'.' '.'</td><td>'. $girlsretentionAverage-$boysretentionAverage .'</td></tr>';
```

The arithmetic `+` and `-` [operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) have the same [precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) as the string concatenation operator (`.`) and all of them are associative from left to right.

This means the subexpression in parentheses (`$i + 1`) is evaluated first and then it is used to compute the rest of the string. All goes well until it reaches:

```
.'</td><td>'. $PPIretentionAverage-$nPPIretentionAverage
```

Because of equal precedence and left-to-right associativity, the already computed string is concatenated with `</td><td>` and then with `$PPIretentionAverage` (after it is converted to string). The resulted string is then used as the left operator of the the arithmetic subtraction `-$nPPIretentionAverage`.

The same thing happens again on `. $girlsretentionAverage-$boysretentionAverage`.

To fix it use parentheses around the arithmetic operators (or extract the arithmetic subexpressions into variables that are computed before the `echo()`):

```
echo '<tr><td>'. ($i + 1) 
     .'</td><td>'. $retentionAverage 
     .'</td><td>'. ($PPIretentionAverage - $nPPIretentionAverage)
     .'</td><td>'.' '
     .'</td><td>'. ($girlsretentionAverage - $boysretentionAverage)
     .'</td></tr>';
```